# How to Identify handling event in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lot of component in my Org. In one component Iam seeing the registered the event,How to come to know where is the handling Event?

Comment: Search in code base? Can you update your question to put more details

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_intro.htm

Use lightning chrome inspector and under events sub tab you can track all the handled and unnhandled events.

Comment: Also, https://mytutorialrack.com/salesforce-lightning-inspector-new-developer-tool-for-google-chrome/  and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7cPTJeN-jc are good resources for learning more about the Lighting Inspector.